# how to get day wise data of this week in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have data entry table(ServiceData) with users data.Columns are Userid,BillDate (type DateTime)and etc.
I need to fetch count of users weekly (current week).

Query

```
select     BillDate
          ,DATENAME(dw,BillDate) as day 
          ,count(BillDate) as total 
from ServiceData 
group by 
BillDate,DATENAME(dw,BillDate) 
order by BillDate desc
```

this is only fetch the day of billdate, but i want to get count of sunday entry , count of monday entry .... from sunday to saturday (current weeek) is this possible?

expected Output

```
    ID   |   TOTAL  |   DAY
   --------------------------
    1    |    23    |   Sun
    2    |    54    |   Mon
    3    |    17    |   Tues
    4    |    56    |   Thus
    5    |    45    |   Fri
    6    |    78    |   Sat
```

Comment: You only show us the expected output. how about the sample input ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please [edit] your question and add a bit more information. Could you provide us with some sample data of the table `ServiceData`. Please also let us know what query you've tried already yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
  row_number() over (order by (SELECT 1)) ID,
  count(*) Total,
  LEFT(Datename(weekday, Cast(Billdate as date)), 3) Day
FROM 
  ServiceData
WHERE
  BillDate >= dateadd(week, datediff(d, -1, getdate()-2)/7, -1)
GROUP BY
  Cast(Billdate as date)
ORDER BY
  Cast(Billdate as date)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer