# how to get data of this week day wise in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have data entry table(ServiceData) with users data.Columns are Userid,BillDate (type DateTime)and etc.
I need to fetch count of users weekly (current week).

**Query**

```
select BillDate,DATENAME(dw,BillDate) as day ,count(BillDate) as total 
from ServiceData 
group by  BillDate,DATENAME(dw,BillDate) 
order by BillDate desc
```

this only fetches the day of billdate, but i want the count of sunday entries , count of monday entries - from sunday to saturday (current weeek). Is this possible?

expected Output

```
    ID   |   TOTAL  |   DAY
   --------------------------
    1    |    23    |   Sun
    2    |    54    |   Mon
    3    |    17    |   Tues
    4    |    56    |   Thus
    5    |    45    |   Fri
    6    |    78    |   Sat
```

Comment: If you expect `ID|TOTAL|DAY`, why do you select `BillDate|day|total`? What is the `ID` column?

Comment: `I need to fetch count of users` vs `count(BillDate)` - where is `user` here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get day wise data of this week in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52381935/how-to-get-day-wise-data-of-this-week-in-sql-server)

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice.